# win32com.client.dynamic.dispatch("word.application") not able to boot MSword intermittently and return None on open file

Tags: python-3.x, vba, win32com

file - C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\temp\b2833343-4013-4922-9a28-4c81e4332b61\1d7621c3-245e-4b8e-99f5-88b764172b31.docx

response <win32com.gen_py.None.Document>

same request
file - C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\temp\b2833343-4013-4922-9a28-4c81e4332b61\1d7621c3-245e-4b8e-99f5-88b764172b31.docx

response None